# Creating a HTML list in View from server Controller in PHP

Tags: php, html, list

I've got a list of "sites" in an SQL database that I'd like to display on a web page. I need to create a div ID for every site. For the time being I'm doing this (fetch the table into a $_SESSION array, get and display the name of the sites in a loop and do an echo):

```
 <div id='leftnavigation1' class="leftnavigation">
       <ul>
           <?php
                $maxKeys = max(array_keys($_SESSION['usersmeter'])); //check how many sites are in the usersmeter table
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxKeys; $i++) { //loop every key in the array
                            $siteName = $_SESSION['usersmeter'][$i]['siteName'];    
                echo "<li id='siteID$i'><a href='#'><span>" . $siteName . "</span></a></li>"; //display the name of the sites
                }
            ?>                        
       </ul>
 </div>
```

It works well but I think it is a bad practice to include php code into the View.

How else can I do? An AJAX in Javascript ?

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest doing a `foreach` loop and if you really want to keep your HTML clean, then use a template engine like Twig or Smarty or any other.

Comment: @Janisimo Thanks I'll have a look at these templates, but not sure I'll be able to install it as I'm using a mutualized hosting.

Comment: there shouldn't be any problems installing it because it is just a PHP library that you include in your project and use it :) I prefer TWIG and use it for all my projects. It's really sexy and it makes HTML sexy too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Like that you will br try:

 <?php    

    $my_array = array(
         'GSU4300' => 'Lili Markina',
         'GSU4301' => 'John Kokina',
         'GSU4304' => 'Bill Clinong',
         'GSU4305' => 'Obamark Chiko'
    );

    echo '<ul id="somethig">';
    foreach ($my_array as $k => $v) {
        echo '<li id="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a foreach instead.